# ! Missing $ inserted

Tags: errors, paths

im experiencing a kind of weird error. I receive the "! Missing $ inserted." error message for line 727. The problem: the line is empty! In the error message he seems to load an R document that I tried to include before. However, I have deleted this line of code as I have spaces in the folder paths. Now, I can work with my file at all. Can you please help? My last save is 24h old... 
When i open the file with TexMaker I always receive a "File not found" error message.

Even if I shorten the document to have <727 lines, I still get an error for line 727

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{eurosym}    
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} 
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.0cm}


\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}

\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{geometry}
%%% PRINTING OPTIONS
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=33mm,right=33mm,
bindingoffset=0mm, top=25mm,bottom=20mm}

\OnehalfSpacing

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{article}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}


%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING USING THE FANCYHDR PACKAGE
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}   %%% Show Chapter left in Header
%\lhead{\leftmark}  %%% Show Section left in Header
\cfoot{\thepage}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents


%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%

\begin{document}


\end{tabular}

\clearpage

\chapter{Results}

\section{Placeholder}




\appendix
\chapter{The Internal Ratings-Based Approach of the Basel II Concept}
\[Capital = \left\{45\times N \left[\frac{IN(PD)}{\sqrt{1-R}} + \frac{\sqrt{R} \times IN(0.999)}{\sqrt{1-R}}\right] - 45 \times PD \right\} \times \left[\frac{1+(M-2.5) \times b(PD)}{1-1.5 \times b(PD}\right]\]

\chapter{Second Appendix}


\clearpage
%\markboth{BIBLIOGRAPHY}{}  %%% BIBLIOGRAPHY in Header
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References}
\clearpage

\end{document}





! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.727 ...is/R/Down-and-in Call/down-and-in_call.R}

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.


! Package Listings Error: File `C:/Users/User/Documents/Master Thesis/R/Down-an
d-in Call/down-and-in_call(.R)' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: R)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.727 ...is/R/Down-and-in Call/down-and-in_call.R}


*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note sure if that works as a MWE. Sorry, I'm just working with Latex since a couple of weeks and until now I was always able to identify the errors myself.

Comment: Changing the name `Call/down-and-in_call.R` for some without underscore `_` may be a simple way to solve your problem.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but that line of code does not exist anymore. I deleted it the \lstinputlisting{} argument as the error appeared first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reduce your example to the minimum working one. To avoid messing with the `filecontents` routine, try this most minimal example. Create an R file, name it **my.R** and add this line only (if dollar signs and underscores are the suspects, why not try them?):

```
data$var <- a_1
```

Then, try this LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=R]{my.R}
\end{document}
```

You should get something like this:
[image: Source code listing]

Fine? Try to copy half of your `down-and-in_call.R` into `my.R` and compile it. It works? Good. Does not work? Continue bisecting till you find the problematic line (`listings` does not handle UTF-8 well, for example). Good? Add the packages from your preamble.

And in case of any trouble, do not forget to do the cleanup of helper files. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks Andrei. If I try to compile that almost virgin document, I receive three "Log file not found" error pop ups. Any idea?

Comment: Which editor do you use (TeXStudio, TeXworks, WinEdt, ...)? Which OS and which LaTeX distribution (MiKTeX or TeXLive)?

Comment: @Relam It is always a good idea to strip even the logs and PDFs, remaining only with the .tex source and .R code. Then, in order to go full virgin, you should open up the command line in your folder (in Windows, Shift+Right-click on the empty space in your folder and “Open Command Window”, in Linux just call the terminal from that folder or `cd` there) and try executing `pdflatex myfile.tex`. The purest thing possible. If there is an error, the problem is with your LaTeX distribution. If not, your text editor is the culprit.

Comment: Tekmaker with Miktex. I just reinstalled Miktex tried to compile the last backup (~24h ago) and now receive the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Command \footruleskip already defined.

Comment: @Relam TeXmaker can be quite quirky and quaint. Just for testing purposes, try `pdflatex`ing your document either from the Windows command prompt (as described above) or from the TeXWorks editor (included in the “Complete” installation). Does any of those complain?

Comment: @Relam Check if you `\newcommand`ed or `\def`ined  `\footruleskip`. If not, you have a package clash. As I told you: remove all packages. Add essential ones (`inputenc`, `fontenc`, ams stuff, `microtype`). Then the prettifying ones (`booktabs`, `eurosym` etc). Always compile two times because on the first run, it updates the external files.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrei. After reinstalling Miktex and Texmaker and adding `\let\footruleskip\undefined` to overcome the footruleskip error the file finally works again. For some reason it seems to be a version that is a couple of hours old but for the moment I don't care! Again, thank you! Any suggestions for the best possible way to backup my work every hour on order not to fuck up my whole file again?

Comment: Use Dropbox (or any other cloud storage). It is free, and you have a month of version history. Just put your project there and compile from there. Immensely useful as a backup tool. Helped me so many times after my colleagues had broken things in shared folders. If this helps, please mark this question as “Solved”. Good luck! P.S. When you become a TeXpert, you might want to try version management tools, e.g. Git.